# SwiftUI scroll view partially displays last item in Mac app

Tags: macos, scrollview, swiftui

How do I properly setup a ScrollView with SwiftUI in a Mac app? The example below clips the last item.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NameRow: View {

    var name: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("\(name)")
            Spacer()
            Divider()
        }.frame(width: 100, height: 40)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let names = ["Homer", "Marge", "Lisa", "Bart", "Maggie", "Krusty", "Burns", "Nelson", "Otto"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    NameRow(name: name)
                }
            }
        }.frame(width: 100, height: 160)
    }
}
```

As shown in the image, the last item is clipped by the window. This view is scrolled to the bottom but the "Otto" item does not fully display.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `.fullSizeContentView` from the `window` initialization in `AppDelegate.swift` so it looks like the following, then it will fully display the list.

```swift
window = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
    styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable],
    backing: .buffered, defer: false)
```

I don't know if this is a bug or by design.

Comment: Removing `. fullSizeContentView ` fixes the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.